# Remove � character from the text

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I am trying to remove � symbol from text, but my method is not working.

[image]

This my code to remove the symbol.

```
public static function cleanText($text) {
    $textStripped = strip_tags($text);                  // Strip HTML Tags
    $textStripped = html_entity_decode($textStripped);  // Clean up things like &amp;
    $textStripped = urldecode($textStripped);           // Strip out any url-encoded stuff
    return $textStripped;
}
```

The page encoding is utf-8.

Why do I have this symbol?
Could you please give more details about it?

Comment: This can be a problem when treating these types of strings using the standard string handling functions (i.e. substr), if you need to do any manipulation using this sort of method - use the mb_ methods if available (mb_substr) as they deal with multi-byte characters better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an invalid UTF-8 character (probably the result of something getting truncated). You can get rid of them using [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

```
public static function cleanText($text) {
    $textStripped = strip_tags($text);                  // Strip HTML Tags
    $textStripped = html_entity_decode($textStripped);  // Clean up things like &amp;
    $textStripped = urldecode($textStripped);           // Strip out any url-encoded stuff
    return iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$textStripped);
}
```

Comment: @AhmadSamilo can you provide more details? It looks like you're trying to add an ellipsis to the text which would mean you're truncating it, are you trying to clean it up before or after you do this?

Comment: This is true I call the method like this <?php echo Blog::cleanText(substr(strip_tags($model->introduction), 0, $size); ?>

Comment: @AhmadSamilo in this case maybe switching to `mb_substr` is a better solution. In fact just pretend the built-in PHP string functions don't exist for you and switch to [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) for everything.I've also updated my code in case it makes any difference now.